# How to stop backup being deleted as soon as it is completed?

Tags: bash, ftp, backup, lftp, duplicity

Duplicity full backup via ftp completes, then is deleted, all with no user action.

There are 2 things I would like to know;

- is there anything in the information below that explains this problem?
- where can I find log output from duplicity that might shed some light?

Calling duplicity's [lftpbackend](https://duplicity.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) module from a script (full script at end of question).

```
# Do backup
duplicity $Options "$Source"  "$Dest"
```

where:
`Dest=ftp://frodo@192.168.1.46/Public/backup`
Deletion after backup does not happen when $Dest is a local disk rather than ftp i.e.
`Dest=file://'/mnt/backup/root_backup/'`
As far as I can tell, no other duplicity jobs are using the ftp $Dest at the same time. I see one duplicity process using ps.Journalctl also only shows 1 job running as I write this;

```
journalctl | grep -ia "backup_"
an 02 09:12:27 PC01 anacron[2828910]: Job `backup_local' started
Jan 02 09:14:08 PC01 anacron[2828910]: Job `backup_local' terminated (exit status: 1) (mailing output)
Jan 02 09:42:27 PC01 anacron[2828910]: Job `backup_NAS' started
```

The following commands are in both the ftp & local disk versions of the script.
They are immediately after the backup command. Deletions happen immediately after backup.

```
duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 2 --force "$Dest"
duplicity cleanup --force "$Dest"
```

However;

- neither command should delete ALL backed up data;
- the deletion occurs with the ftp backend, not the local disk backend.

The log for the ftp daemon on the destination NAS shows that deletions are being commanded via ftp from the source PC.

```
pid 2] CONNECT:
[pid 1] [frodo] OK LOGIN:
[pid 3] [frodo] OK DELETE:, "/Public/backup/duplicity-full.20231231T040136Z.vol897.difftar.gpg"
```

Duplicity is the only possible source of these ftp commands.
If someone knows where to find duplicity log output that might help me.

System info:

name -a
Linux PC01 6.2.0-1018-lowlatency #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 11:27:56 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

duplicity --version
duplicity 0.8.21

lftp -v
LFTP | Version 4.9.2 | Copyright (c) 1996-2020 Alexander V. Lukyanov

---- FULL SCRIPT----

```
#!/bin/sh
# shebang '!/bin/sh' refers to a symlink to default shell on system

# Provides:     Backup
# Requires:     duplicity, wmctrl, zenity, CLI shell, lftp
# Execution: via anacron, as root, script stored in /etc/cron.daily

# Filename:     backup_PC01_NAS.sh
# Version:      1 of 30.12.2023
# Author:       David Morrell (dmgen@posteo.net)

# Backup syntax
# duplicity [full|incremental] [options] source_directory target_url

# Set variables so duplicity does not prompt for them when the script is run N.B. script must be stored in secure location.
# Always unset variables at end of script i.e. unset <varname>
export PASSPHRASE='Fred'        # Set passphrase for GPG  key used to encrypt backup
# Set password for remote backend if required (works with most backends, FTP & others)
export FTP_PASSWORD='u&me4eva'

# Set other control variables
SectionSeparator='===================================================================='
Source='/'
Dest=ftp://frodo@192.168.1.46/Public/backup
ExcludeList=''/opt/config/duplicity/exclude_list''
IncludeList=''/opt/config/duplicity/include_list''
Options="--name='Backup_PC01_NAS'
 --full-if-older-than 1M
 --verbosity=info
 --archive=/mnt/backup/duplicity_archive
 --tempdir=/mnt/backup/duplicity_temp_NAS
 --exclude-filelist="$ExcludeList"
 --include-filelist="$IncludeList""

echo
echo 'Starting backup...'
echo $SectionSeparator
echo
echo 'Variables'
echo 'Source = ' $Source
echo 'Dest = ' $Dest
echo 'Exclude = ' $ExcludeList
echo 'Include = ' $IncludeList
echo 'Options = ' $Options
echo

# Do backup
duplicity $Options "$Source"  "$Dest"

# Do clean up
echo 'Starting clean up...'
echo $SectionSeparator
echo
duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 2 --force "$Dest"
duplicity cleanup --force "$Dest"

echo
echo 'Done'
echo $SectionSeparator

echo

lastrun='Last run '$(date)
collstatus=$(duplicity collection-status $Dest | tail)

# Unset passphrase
unset PASSPHRASE
# unset FTP_PASSWORD

# Log last run
echo "$SectionSeparator\n$lastrun\n$SectionSeparator\n$collstatus" > lastrun.txt

# Show dialog with status of collection after last run
sleep 1
wmctrl -F -a "INFO" -b add,above & (zenity --display=:0.0 --width=600 --height=300 --info --title="Backup Check NAS" --text="$collstatus")

# --- EOF ---
```

[duplicity]

Comment: I don't know anything about _duplicity_, but my feeling is that this is related to one of two cleanup commands in your script. Comment them out to find, which one is the culprit. Then ask this question again at [su], because it is not related to programming, but about the usage of `duplicity`.

Comment: agreed, this is too unspecific to be answered here. join the duplicity ML https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/duplicity-talk and post it there or try your luck by creating an issue on https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues .